# navigation menu with two levels in xsl

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have a problem, I'm writing a html with xml. I used to write a navigation menu with dropdowns by using notepad++. By now I'm using Oxygen and the navigation menu doesn't work. 
The problem is that the dropdowns aren't available. The rest is OK.
This is a part of my code:

```
 ul#css3menu1 a {
      width: 100px;
      display : block;
      vertical-align : middle;
      text-align : left;
      text-decoration : none;
      font : bold 14px 50;
      background-color : #FFFFFF;
      text-shadow : 0 0 1px #FFF;
      cursor : pointer;
      padding : 10px;
      background-color : #FFFFFF;
      background-image : #000000;
      color:#000; 
      background-repeat : no-repeat;
      background-position : 0 0;
      font: 14px Courir;
      border-width : 0 0 0 1px;
      border-style : solid;
      border-color : #C0C0C0;
 } 

 ul#css3menu1 ul {
      display : none;
      position : absolute;
      left : 0;
      top : 100%;
      box-shadow : 3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
      background-color : #COCOCO;
      border-radius : 6px;
      border-color : #000000;
      padding : 0 10px 10px;
 }  


 ul#css3menu1 li:hover > * {
      display : block;
 }
 <!--normally in this part the second level gets available !?!?!-->
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with this code for the hover part:

```
 ul#css3menu1 ul:hover {
      display : block;
 }
```

The problem is that `ul` is hidden because of `display: none;` property so when you change display to block for children, i.e. `li` and children elements, it doesn't work because `ul` is still hidden.